# How to map complex class with automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have to namespaces VM and GM.
Both having classes Employee.
Employee contain Department.
I want to map VM.Employee to GM.Employee.
Mapper is not allowing me to map Department.

```
class VM.Employee 
{
    int Id {get;set;}   
    int Name {get;set;}   
    VM.Department dept{get;set;}
}

class VM.Department 
{
    int Id {get;set;}   
    int Name {get;set;}  
}

class GM.Employee 
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    int Name {get;set;}
    GM.Department dept{get;set;}
}

class GM.Department 
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    int Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need 2 identical classes for Department?

Comment: In future GM model may contain some extra properties. and VM is to interact with DB.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's not that difficult. You can manually map field by field, something along the lines of this:

```
       Mapper.CreateMap<VM.Employee, GM.Employee>()
              .ForMember(vm => vm.Department,
                         mapping => mapping.MapFrom(gm => gm.Department))

       Mapper.CreateMap<VM.Department, GM.Department>()
              .ForMember(vm => vm.SomeFieldOfVmDepartment,
                         mapping => mapping.MapFrom(gm => gm.SomeFieldOfGmDepartment))
              .ForMember(vm => vm.AnotherField,
                         mapping => mapping.MapFrom(gm => gm.AnotherField))
```

Automapper is convention based and will automatically match fields that are named identically, when you map two classes. However, when the classes that you want to map have different fields (names or number of fields differ), Automapper cannot possibly know which of the fields you want to map to, so you have to explicitly tell it so.

You should of course, read AutoMapper docs for more info:
[Automapper Documentation](https://automapper.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: It is near to my requirement. But i have to use Department class to be common. So i am using now Department class from VM namespace for both Employee class. But i want to use separate Department i.e VM.Department  for VM.Employee and GM.Department for GM.Employee

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve, but you can use 2 different Department classes as long as you map them. Baiscally, you map the different department classes, then you map the Employees classes (like in the answer above)

Comment: Mapper.CreateMap<VM.Employee, GM.Employee>()
              .ForMember(vm => vm.Department,
                         mapping => mapping.MapFrom(gm => gm.Department)) this don't work Mapper.CreateMap<VM.Employee, GM.Employee>()
              .ForMember(vm => vm.Department,
                         mapping => mapping.MapFrom(VM=> VM.Department)) works.